# Why the users of main Domain controller can't logon from child domain in the other site to it's Domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, user-accounts

I've **A** & **B** site , every site have 1 server , the **A** have main domain **innovation.com** the first domain controller , the other is **alex.innovation.com** the second domain controller . the both server is Windows Server 2008.
the problem is the users of the first domain **innovation.com** can't log on from **B** site except the Administrator of the first site **innovation.com**. 
i have been trying to enter user@innovation.com from **B** site, it send me message like that

> you are not allowed to logon . because you are using logon method is not allowed on this computer

is there way to solve this problem and how? 
thanks for every one.

Answer (score 0):

well this sounds to me like domain security policy, check logon rights under the GPO.